# Emacs ignores display-fill-column-indicator-character settings

Tags: display, fill-column

I have these settings in my `init.el`:

```
(global-display-fill-column-indicator-mode 1)
(setq-default fill-column 120)
(setq-default display-fill-column-indicator t)
(setq-default display-fill-column-indicator-character ?|)
```

But my fill column indicator is still a block, not a vertical line (`|`):

[image]

`setq-default fill-column 120` takes effect so I'm sure `init.el` is loaded correctly. But no matter how I set `display-fill-column-indicator-character` nothing changes.

I'm on Windows if that matters.

**Edit:**

This is the culprit:

```
(use-package emacs
  :config
  (load-theme 'modus-vivendi))
```

But I don't understand how. I set `display-fill-column-indicator-character` *after* I load the theme, but it still doesn't take effects.

Comment: Did you test it with other custom configs disabled (`emacs -q`)?

Comment: @Y.E. Thank you. I didn't know about this (it's my first day using Emacs). It seems that the ``'modus-vivendi` theme is causing the problem. But I don't understand how it works: I set `display-fill-column-indicator-character` *after* I apply the theme. Why isn't it still taking effects?

Comment: You're welcome. See [modus-vivendi docs](https://protesilaos.com/emacs/modus-themes#h:2a602816-bc1b-45bf-9675-4cbbd7bf6cab) for a starter and [maybe try tweaking line-spacing](https://gitlab.com/protesilaos/modus-themes/-/issues/148#note_490008868).